# Module build failed , vue-router.esm.js in Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I'm new to VueJs and implemented the [cli-plugin-unit-jest](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/tree/dev/packages/%40vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest) for my project.Once i aded it to project it's show me below error

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.esm.js
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/media/abc/049A20AD9A209CE4/test/node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.esm.js'
```

i have deleted `node_module` directory and re installed it.but still showing this error.

Answer (score 15):

Just restart your server:

```js
npm run serve
```

Comment: Why will restarting the server fix this problem?

Comment: It certainly didn't for me.

Answer (score 3):

Today I stumbled about the same problem with vue-router. You can fix this by following this steps:

```
cd node_modules/vue-router
npm install
npm run build
```

After that you have to restart

```
npm run serve
```

Source:
https://router.vuejs.org/installation.html#dev-build